# Popping noise from Asus G60 laptop speakers

Tags: windows-7, laptop, speakers

Speakers make a popping sound when Windows 7 starts from the Login page and throughout the time it's on. Music and application sounds do not work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 update at 5 A.M. fixed the problem. Odd.